# How to autoreboot an ec2 amazon linux instance after 1st start during autoscaling? (to start working with it from the 2nd start only)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-ami, amazon-linux

I have a problem, that when I launch an instance from an AMI, the instance doesn't respond on ssh or http, but it works normally after I restart it (so from the 2nd start).

I'm still troubleshooting this behaviour, so I decided to try to ask the following:

What's the best/most simple way to make an instance reboot after it's first launch/start from an AMI in an autoscaling environment?

AMI is an Amazon Linux one (kernel 4.4 or 4.9).

Thanks!

UPDATE: Fixed it :) Now a new instance from that AMI launches & starts working from the 1st boot! :)

I've updated several system packages (that helped), removed 2nd network interface, custom route & iptables rules, which were applied at boot (removed all that before with no result).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a great approach. You'd have to configure your ELB to allow more time for the instance to come up, and you can't scale as quickly. As a stopgap may be it's ok, but perhaps you could put more effort into fixing the problem or replacing the AMI. I guess you could use a userdata script or similar to do this, though I've never tried.

Comment: Are you using the stock ami ? Do you have any user data scripts running? What region and instance type? Do the system and status checks go green before you reboot?

Comment: It's not a stock AMI, but it's based on Amazon Linux with 4.9 kernel. No user data scripts running. US east, c48xlarge. Yes, both go to green.